# Flutter Webview - trapping touchstart events on Android

Tags: android, flutter, webview, long-press, touchstart

This [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37927) posted on Github seems to suggest that `touch events` are deliberately suppressed in the Android implementation ostensibly to enable the detection of `longpresses` for the purposes of copy/paste.

My own application absolutely needs to be able to trap touch events - and longpress text selections have no relevance whatsoever.  I thought I would do this by using a local copy of the Flutter [webview implementation code](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/2b2ca6687e49e5e1067a11939fc78f2013c6fbd4/packages/webview_flutter), and then suppressing the `longpress` filter.  The relevant code in `webview_android.dart` reads

> We prevent text selection by intercepting the long press event.
>     This is a temporary stop gap due to issues with text selection on Android:
>     https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24585 - the text selection
>     dialog is not responding to touch events.
>     https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24584 - the text selection
>     handles are not showing.
>     TODO(amirh): remove this when the issues above are fixed.
>     onLongPress: () {},

To that end I downloaded the Flutter source and ensured that `webview_flutter` was available in a folder bearing that name two levels below my Flutter project root folder.  After modifying `pubspec.yaml` to read

```
  webview_flutter:
    path: ../../webview_flutter
```

and running `flutter clean && flutter run` the APK was built and installed on my test device.  However, it then reported

> Setting up FlutterEngine.
>     D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(24999): No preferred FlutterEngine was provided. Creating a new 
>     FlutterEngine for this FlutterFragment.
>     W/FlutterEngine(24999): Tried to automatically register plugins with FlutterEngine 
>     (io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@9480b1a) but could not find and invoke the 
>     GeneratedPluginRegistrant.

I do not understand this message.  I'd be most obliged to anyone who might be able to tell me how/whether it can be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have found: as far as I can tell the official Flutter webview is a neglected step child.  There are bugs dating back three years that have received little attention.  Some of its "features" such as `longPress` suppression/detection are downright ridiculous.

I switched to using [Flutter Webview plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) which fixes most of the issues I had encountered.   Just remember to enable `withzoom:true`.  I found that the webview does not automatically trap `onPause` and `onResume` events.  I handled this as follows

```
 @override void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) 
 {
  setState(() 
  {
   appState = state;
   switch(state)
   {
    case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
    case AppLifecycleState.paused:
         FlutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript('callBack()');break;//onPause
    case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
         FlutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript('callBack()');break;//onResume 
   }
  });
 }
```

You will have to ensure that

- You have a suitably initialized instance of the `FlutterWebviewPlugin` singleton
- In your Javascript you have defined `callBack`

I should mention that I start from `WidgetsApp` and the above code is in the stateful class it uses with `with WidgetsBindingObserver`

Answer (score 0):

I have now accidentally stumbled upon a way out of the "no touch events in Android" issue that dog Flutter Webview.  Rather than delete my question I felt it would be more useful to others to leave it here with the solution I have found.

I started off with the intention of trapping Touch events in Flutter myself and then transmitting them to the WebView via `evaluateJavascript`.  To that end I changed my Widget structure so as to wrap the WebView in a Listener.  My entire Widget builder code is shown below.

```
@override Widget build(BuildContext context) 
{
 SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]);   

 return WidgetsApp
 (
  onGenerateRoute:makeWebView,
  color:Color.fromRGBO(0,128,255,1.0)
 );
} 


Route makeWebView(RouteSettings settings)
{
 return new PageRouteBuilder
 (
  pageBuilder:(BuildContext context,Animation<double> animation,Animation<double> 
  secondaryAnimation)
  {
   return SafeArea
   (
    child:Listener
    (
     child: SizedBox.expand
     (
      child:WebView
      (
       debuggingEnabled:true, 
       initialUrl:'',
       javascriptMode:JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
       onWebViewCreated:registerController,
       javascriptChannels:Set.from
       ([JavascriptChannel(name:'JSBridge',onMessageReceived:handleMessage)]),
      ),
     ),
    )
   );
  });
 }
```

Much to my surprise simply doing this made the encpasulated Flutter WebView respond to `touch#` events with no pesky `LongPress` issues getting in the way.  It is not clear to me just why this should happen - perhaps someone else here can explain.

A few notes on my code above

- I use WebViews that take up the entire device screen in landscape format - both on iOS and on Android
- I use WidgetsApp rather than MaterialApp to provide the basic scaffolding
- SafeArea ensures that the app consumes space that is legitimately available to it
- Listener is what does the magic here  and makes Touch events available in WebView, even on Android
- WebView is the main player here where all the action happens.  In front end JavaScript you just need to capture `touchstart`, `touchmove` and `touchend` events on the `document.body`.

You can read up more on the various widgets I have used here in the [Flutter Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/widgets-library.html).